# UIPageViewController dots not showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

Everything working fine but dots not showing. My code is...

```
import UIKit

class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    dataSource = self

    if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
        setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                           direction: .forward,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: nil)
    }

}

private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {

    return [self.newColoredViewController(color: ""),
            self.newColoredViewController(color: "Second"),
            self.newColoredViewController(color: "Third")]
}()

private func newColoredViewController(color: String) -> UIViewController {

    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(color)ViewController")
}

}


// MARK: UIPageViewControllerDataSource

extension MyPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

        guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        setupPageControl()
        return orderedViewControllers.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    private func setupPageControl() {
        let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
        appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`

Comment: in storyboard I fixed it, see my updated qusetion

Comment: this method `presentationCountForPageViewController` called ?

Comment: No not calling ....

Comment: @ Prashant Tukadiya, actually I'm using PageViewController but its not calling. is there any necessity to call delegates

Comment: presentationCountForPageViewController is in datasource so  it is fine. If you have copy paste code from tutorial then make sure it is as per latest swift syntax

Comment: I think its not updated one , but above code working fine, can you please solve the above issue

Comment: @ Prashant Tukadiya, can you please suggest any tutorial how to add PageViewController to existing view controller and load one more three viewcontrollers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the **wrong version of those functions**.

In order to show UIPageControl, you need to implement two optional datasource methods. Just return the whole number of pages for **presentationCount** and the initially selected index for **presentationIndex**

```
func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    setupPageControl()
    return orderedViewControllers.count
    }

func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, its working but background getting black colour. how to remove

Comment: Set UIPageControl backgroundColor to white:
  UIPageControl.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white

Comment: @ Hitesh Borse , thank you but can it's not satisfied my requirement can you please suggest how to add PageViewController to exist ViewController and load one more three viewcontrollers . Can you suggest any code or tutorial for me.

Comment: https://medium.com/@LKChk/ios-use-uipageviewcontroller-to-build-swipe-views-dc36b8225013

Comment: Or just search: Add view controller as **child view** controller

Comment: Thank you, this Code worked for me with few changes, https://samwize.com/2016/03/08/using-uipageviewcontroller-with-custom-uipagecontrol/

Answer (score 0):

you should add page view controller data source and number of pages : 
`pageControl.numberOfPages = 3`